# Showing action sheet when iPhone app launches the first time iOS 8

Tags: swift, ios8, uiactionsheet

My iPhone app needs to display the action sheet only when the app launches the first time. How do i get this accomplished in Swift? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You want to look at UIAlertController. UIActionSheet is deprecated. It's very easy to use.

With Obj-C you create an instance with a conventience method, setting the style to actionSheet. Then call addAction for each "button" you want on your sheet. Here is some code you can work from:

```
- (IBAction)actionButtonAction:(id)sender {
    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Select an action" message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

    [alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Share Data" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
        // Your activity
    }]];

    [alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Share Plot" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
        // Your activity
    }]];



    [alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
        // User cancelled
    }]];

    // Present VC. 
    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:^{

    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have a view controller that opens when the application starts up (when you first start a swift project, your storyboard will have one view controller in it, this is the root controller, and the initial "viewController.swift" file that's generated in the project is hooked up to it.

from that root controller (or any view controller that you're using as the initial view controller)

you can create, configure, and present a UIAlertController that is configured for the ActionSheet style in the ViewDidAppear method.

Just like this

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    }



override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let userDefaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    let firstTimeLoggingIn: Bool? = userDefaults.objectForKey("firstTimeLogin") as? Bool

    if (firstTimeLoggingIn == nil) {
        userDefaults.setBool(true, forKey: "firstTimeLogin")
        actionSheetForFirstLogin()
    }

}

func actionSheetForFirstLogin() {
    let actionSheet: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "the  title", message: "the message", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

    let callActionHandler = { (action:UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        let alertMessage = UIAlertController(title: action.title, message: "You chose an action", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        alertMessage.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(alertMessage, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    let action1: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "action title 1", style: .Default, handler:callActionHandler)

    let action2: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "action title 2", style: .Default, handler:callActionHandler)

    actionSheet.addAction(action1)
    actionSheet.addAction(action2)

    presentViewController(actionSheet, animated: true, completion:nil)
}

}
```

this also separates the action handler for the action sheet, so you can see how to create them independently and add them. In this example i've only created one, and inspected the actions title to display the alert that will be displayed based on the choice; however, you could always create separate actions.

**Edit**

I've added NSUserDefaults to handle the first time login scenario

Comment: Thank you domitall for your quick reply. I am aware of how to use UIAlertController. My issue is that i would like to have it only come up when my app is launched by the user the first time and at predefined intervals.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by predefined intervals, a time interval if a person has logged in before maybe? Either way, I did add an edit to handle the first time login with NSUserDefaults. If you wanted to run this over a time interval, you could use NSTimer, with a selector that names the "actionSheetForFirstLogin" method above